# Pulley/winch knot + spring for holding up heavy punching bag

Tags: mounting, load-bearing

I want to hang a heavy punching bag with a pulley and a heavy duty spring. I currently have four lengths of rated chain attached to a hook, a heavy duty spring attached with a caribiner, then a rated eye screw.

Any suggestions to add a pulley?

[image]

Comment: A) Can you please clarify _where_ this pulley is supposed to go? B) Have you reviewed any of the "Related Posts" (in the column to the right) to ensure that you're not going to overload your roof? It looks like you're hanging the bag off of a 2x6, not a 2x4, but those 2x4 roof joists may not quite be up to the task of holding up a swinging heavy bag.

Comment: That is my question. Can I add a pulley here? Or should I just stay with the rated chains, spring and eye screw?

Comment: Maybe I'm just dense today, but I don't understand where the pulley would go or what it's for. Maybe a sketch or two showing where _you_ think the pulley could go. What would the advantage be of putting a pulley in the system?  I would reiterate that I'm not certain that your joist/rafter setup is sufficient for supporting the weight of a moving heavy bag.

Comment: Pulley would enable me to remove it by myself. But I am thinking it is too many pieces in the system. Better off keeping the spring to reduce the force.

Comment: Do you mean a pulley, or do you mean a block and tackle, which would reduce the force required to lift the bag? In either case, the answer is "sure". You need to revise to ask something more specific.

Comment: I will again refer you to the "related questions" section in the right-hand column where there should be several questions about hanging a heavy bag from the rafters. As you get busy punching and/or kicking the thing, there _will_ be a _lot_ of kinetic energy and your rafters may well not be up to the task of supporting the _moving_ bag _and_ the roof, all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Put the pulley above the spring, and in no way connected to the spring, or the chain.

Use it only for lifting the bag, so that the bag can be unhooked and lowered to the ground.

The rope should be loose, or disconnected, during the normal use of the bag.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a single pulley won't help much with mechanical advantage.  You'd just be pulling diagonally down on a rope with the same force as it would take to lift the bag in the first place.

Instead you'd want two pulleys, with the end of your rope secured to the rafters/beams.  Then it goes down through a pulley attached to bag, then up to a second pulley hanging from the rafter, and finally down to your hand.  This gives you a 3:1 advantage but you have to pull three times as much rope through.

This pulley would only be for lifting, you'd still need to secure it with the chains and detangler and spring as pictured.